# Solving Rational Equations w/ a Trinomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{7}{2x^2-x-1}=\frac{5}{x-1}$$

I've factored it to
$$\frac{7}{2x(x-1)(x-1)}=\frac{5}{x-1}$$

and then multiplied everything by
$$\frac{2x(x-1)(x-1)}{1}$$

to get $$7=5(2x)(x-1)$$

And this is where I'm stuck. Do I multiply the terms on the right side or subtract one to the other?

Comment: a second degree polynomial cant factor to get a $x^3$ if you multiply factors together

Comment: If you had the right factorization then what you could do is to multiply with least common divisor, then you would get an easier one.

Comment: Okay, yes, I misread the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You factored incorrectly.

You should have $\displaystyle \frac{7}{2x^2-x-1}=\frac{5}{x-1}$.

That would become $\displaystyle \frac{7}{(2x+1)(x-1)}=\frac{5}{x-1}$

Multiply both sides by $\displaystyle (x-1)(2x+1)$ assuming $\displaystyle x \neq 1,-\frac12$ to get $7=5(2x+1)$.

Therefore, $7=10x+5$, then $10x=2$, and so $\displaystyle \boxed{x=\frac{1}{5}}$.

Answer (score 0):

moving all terms to the left and factorizing we get
$$-2\,{\frac {5\,x-1}{ \left( x-1 \right)  \left( 2\,x+1 \right) }}=0$$
from here we get the searched solution.